# Suppress output from non-PowerShell commands?

Tags: powershell, output

I am running a command

```
hg st
```

and then checking it's `$LASTEXITCODE` to check for availability of mercurial in the current directory. I do not care about its output and do not want to show it to my users.

How do I suppress ALL output, success or error?

Since mercurial isn't a PowerShell commandlet `hg st | Out-Null` does not work.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`Out-Null` works just fine with non-PowerShell commands. However, it doesn't suppress output on `STDERR`, only on `STDOUT`. If you want to suppress output on `STDERR` as well you have to redirect that file descriptor to `STDOUT` before piping the output into `Out-Null`:

```
hg st 2>&1 | Out-Null
```

`2>` redirects all output from `STDERR` (file descriptor #2). `&1` merges the redirected output with the output from `STDOUT` (file descriptor #1). The combined output is then printed to `STDOUT` from where the pipe can feed it into `STDIN` of the next command in the pipline (in this case `Out-Null`). See [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) for further information.

Comment: Awesome. That works. Can you explain what the `2>&1` syntax actually means?

Comment: `2>&1` means "redirect standard error to the same place as standard output."

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I believe that's what I said, only that I addressed both parts of the operator separately, because other streams could be merged with STDOUT (the success output stream, actually) as well.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - sure. I didn't notice that you had amended your answer after George Mauer asked for clarification.

Answer (score 10):

A fun thing you can do is to pipe the output to Write-Verbose, then you can still see it if you need it by running your script with the -Verbose switch.

```
ping -n 2 $APP 2>&1 | Write-Verbose
```

Answer (score 7):

Can also do this

```
hg st *> $null
```

[Powershell suppress console output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18780956/#comment27698289_18782669)

Comment: This won't suppress STDERR for example if `hg` is not installed

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Neither does my suggestion. Errors thrown by the host environment are not redirected.

Comment: Note that the `*>` redirection operator is not available prior to PowerShell v3.