# Suppress console output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, output, suppress-warnings, verbosity

I have a call to GPG in the following way in a PowerShell script:

```
$key = & 'gpg' --decrypt "secret.gpg" --quiet --no-verbose > $null
```

I don't want any output from GPG to be seen on the main console when I'm running the script.

Due to my noobness in PowerShell, I don't know how to do this. I searched 
Stack Overflow and googled for a way to do it, found a lot of ways to do it, but non of it worked.

The "> $null" for example has no effect. I found the `--quiet --no-verbose` options for GPG to put less output in the console, still it's not completely quiet, and I'm sure there is a way in PowerShell too.

Comment: See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744451/powershell-suppress-output-from-non-powershell-commands

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suppress stderr output in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969596/how-to-suppress-stderr-output-in-powershell)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[What's the better (cleaner) way to ignore output in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell)*.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try redirecting the output like this:

```
$key = & 'gpg' --decrypt "secret.gpg" --quiet --no-verbose >$null 2>&1
```

Comment: In PowerShell v3 he could redirect all output streams like this: `*>$null`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Perhaps add that as an answer, so it can receive upvotes.

Comment: @DanSolovay Nah. It's just a minor variation of Dave's answer.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer.
| out-null was just not enough.

Answer (score 150):

Try redirecting the output to [Out-Null](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849716.aspx). Like so:

```
$key = & 'gpg' --decrypt "secret.gpg" --quiet --no-verbose | out-null
```

Comment: `>$null` does the same as `| Out-Null`.

Comment: Maybe so..but it would make more sense to use this cmdlet, instead of remembering an arbitrary "hack" to cancel out the output.

Comment: @Erutan409 why is `>$null` a hack? Serious question.

Comment: @theyetiman Matter of opinion, I suppose. Using PowerShell's built-in `Out-Null`, I think, would read better when debugging someone else's code or even your own if it's been a while. It's an intentional function that's provided for the aforementioned problem, too.

Comment: Definitely a matter of opinion, `>$null` is easily guessable for me as linux user

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Comment: I hadn't thought about it much but I had assumed that " > $null" was an alias of " | Out-Null" to allow us CMD and Bash users a quick 'hack' to use it.  However on thinking about it " | Out-Null" does use a pipe, and therefore will need at least one extra execution step over >.....  Might be that " | Out-Null" is to make a standardized usage within powershell,a nd ultimately over-rides " > $null" which would make " > $null" a preferable usage.  Looks like I may have to change my scripts currently using " | Out-Null" to use " > $null" instead.

Comment: Hmm, just did a little googling, and this Stack Exchange Item, seems to show that " > $null" is quite a bit faster at allowing command execution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Comment: I'd be careful with this option, if you are trying to suppress console output but also trying to return results, this will actually return null and not your results.

Answer (score 9):

It is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell), with an answer that contains a time measurement of the different methods.

Conclusion: Use `[void]` or `> $null`.

Comment: Why don't you flag as duplicate then?

Comment: Because I've never done it and was uncertain about it. Now it is flagged.