# Supress output of chromedriver

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, selenium, stdout

According to [the answers in the question "Suppress console output in PowerShell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780956/suppress-console-output-in-powershell) and several other ressources, I should be able to suppress all output by redirecting all ouputs to null on  `chromedriver`.

Powershell, variant 1:

```bsh
./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe --port=8015  *> $null
```

Powershell, variant 2:

```bsh
./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe --port=8015  | Out-Null
```

Powershell, variant 3:

```bsh
[void] (./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe --port=8015)
```

Also on node I do fail to supress output:

```js
var cp = require("child_process");
chromeDriverProcess = await cp.spawn(
    __dirname + '/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe',
    ["--port=8015"],
    {
        stdio:'ignore'
    }
);
```

I still get messages like: `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58230/devtools/browser/18d5a160-cd43-488b-b969-cf91caf3f8df`

Using the switch `--silent` on `chromedriver` and `--log-level=3` on `chrome` does supress some of the outputs, but not the one mentioned above.

How does `chromedriver` output its data?
How do I supress all output done by `chormedriver`?

Comment: have you tried [void](chromedrive.exe ...) ?  ...but if your all-stream redirection to $null doesn't work (*>) then this probably won't either.

Comment: I updated the question. [void](chromedrive.exe ...) does not help either :-(

Comment: Oof here I am with the exact same unanswered question three years later.